# How Can I get Value of ListView and show the value when I click it

Tags: android, listview, click

How Can I get Value of ListView and show the value when I click it?

I get the values from mysql database.

```
public class SearchlistviewActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private ListView lv1;

    private ArrayList<String> arr_sort= new ArrayList<String>();
    int textlength=0;
    private ArrayList<String> map= new ArrayList<String>();

    protected int selected;
    //private  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listItem = new ArrayList<HashMap<String>>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1); 

        getServerData(strURL);

        lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , map));

        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View v, int position,
             long id) {
                Toast.makeText(SearchlistviewActivity.this,"Listed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public static final String strURL = "http://192.168.0.2/ville.php";

    private String getServerData(String returnString ) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ville",""));

        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String http="http://" ;
            String myip ="192.168.0.2" ;
            String vil="/ville.php";
            String myurl=http+myip+vil;

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(myurl);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        // Parse les donnA©es JSON
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                Log.i("log_tag","CostumerOrder: "+json_data.getString("CostumerOrder")+
                        ", OrderPrice: "+json_data.getString("OrderPrice")
                );

                map.add(json_data.getString("CostumerOrder").toString());
            }
        } catch(JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        return returnString; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Have You tried lv1.getAdapter().getItem(position)?

Comment: not yet, I have a question what if I want to put the data of listview that I clicked int a mysql database?

Answer (score 0):

```
String selectedFromList = (listview.getItemAtPosition(position));
Toast.makeText(context, selectedFromList, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

In your on list item click

Comment: What if I want to put the value of ListView that I click on a mysql database?

Comment: myaddtodatabasecose.add(selectedFromList); i assume you already know how to add and remove items

Answer (score 0):

```
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View v, int position,
         long id) {
            Toast.makeText(SearchlistviewActivity.this,"Listed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        });

}
```

in onItemClicke you can get the poistion or index of the item which is clicked and you can get the object by the index from the array and then you can use it any where.

Hope this will help you.